# Critical issues have been reported with the following SDK versions: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.0

Tags: android, google-play-console

**I am uploading my app on google play store and I got these warning**

```
Critical issues have been reported with the following SDK versions:

com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.0
```

What the SDK developer told us:

play-services-tasks v18.0.0 has known issues that can lead to runtime NPEs (NullPointerException) when handling Task results in Kotlin code. We strongly recommend that you avoid using this version. This also impacts the SDKs listed in the December 9, 2021 release, because they all depend on play-services-tasks. A fix for this issue is included in play-services-tasks v18.0.1. See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#december_16_2021

Comment: Have you tried updating your Gradle dependencies to the latest versions? What exactly is your question here?

Comment: yes I have upgraded to latest version. Its shows warning when I upload my app to google play store

Comment: So what is your question? What version are you using? You should post your Gradle file in the question, and clarify what it is you are asking. I still don't see a question in what you have written.

Comment: It happens to me as well. I can verify im using 18.0.1 and im still getting the error, maybe a problem in the store? Have you managed to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue and the firebase team is currently working on it.
Here is the [thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3890) for the same.
This is what the firebase devs have to say

> For context: the SafetyNet SDK is used by Firebase Auth for App Verification.
>
> We are working on a migration path to the Play Integrity API, which we
> expect to make available within the SafetyNet deprecation timeline.
>
> In the meantime, your app will still be uploaded and the warning can
> be disregarded.